# set android:text from strings.xml

Tags: android, xml

I am developing two languages program, so I am trying to set
some text from `res/values-en/strings.xml` but I don't have any idea how to do it

from here

```
<string name="advices">Advices</string>
```

to here

```
<TextView
        android:text="TO HERE <---------"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get text from strings by using `@string` keyword.

```
<TextView
        android:text="@string/advices"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

**and there is an another way to do this :**

->> Right click on the `TextView` on which you want to set text from `strings`. Select `EditText` from the menu or alternatively you can press `F2 Function Key`

[image: right click on text view]

->> Now all `strings` will be listed which are available in your `strings.xml`. Select the required string from list.

[image: select edit text]

->> Now you can see your `string` in your `text view`.

[image: text in text view]

Comment: @Jacek: If you like my answer then you can mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your **res** folder, there will be **values** named folder in which you will have strings.xml file.In that file you have to put your all English String in it.

And now if you want to use another language like **Spanish** then make values-es named folder and put all Spanish meaning for English Language..

and set something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="#999999"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/string_here"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```